# Adding filters to increase SQL performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

Just a basic question...

Do adding more filters increase performance of a table scan?

For example if I have a table with columns with a lot of NULL values but I'm looking only for values > 35.

Is it any faster to do `WHERE something IS NOT NULL AND something > 35` or should I just stick with `WHERE something > 35`.

Running MS SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: DO you have an index?

Comment: Table has four indexes

Comment: Any `something` that is > 35 is already `NOT NULL`. stick with `something > 35`. You can profile both versions to see differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two formulations are equivalent functionally.

When doing a full table scan, the overhead is in loading the pages into the page cache.  Doing the test is a minimal part of the computing effort.  If NULL is checked twice, the difference in performance may be unmeasurable.

The choice between:

```
 where something > 35
```

and

```
where something > 35 and something is not null
```

Is a question of how expressive the query is.  I prefer to be explicit and have the NULL check in the `where` clause.  However, both are equivalent.